# Which of the following sentence sounds more professional

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can you help me in choosing a sentence that is most professional in technology

1. The lamp went out.
2. The lamp died.
3. The lamp was not working.
4. The lamp was out of order.
5. The lamp burned out.

Thank you for you help

Comment: The Lamp went out to dinner? pun intended. I think 3 and 4 sounds more professional to me, but I am no tech guy.

Comment: What's your profession?

Comment: @StoneyB mine or his?

Comment: 'What kind of lamp' could also be vital to the answer.

Comment: @Usernew OP's profession. In some professions "lamp" has a narrow technical meaning which would only be appropriate in #1 or #5.

Comment: @StoneyB what about #2? Will it be appropriate to use for the same lamp you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

> The lamp *went out* - *seems okay*. Especially in the context of 'light', ['go out' means light goes out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/go+out) making it dark. 
>  The lamp died - *seems okay*. However, it's *more* used when [machines](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/die_1#die_1__4) stops working. 
>  The lamp wasn't working - *okay and natural* 
>  The lamp was out of order - *okay*. However, more frequently used for [devices and machines](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/out-of-order) 
>  The lamp burned out - *okay* **but** used more when we mean to say that something has stopped burning because of [*lack of fuel*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/burn+out).

---

My personal choice:

Option 3 if you mean ['lamp' like this.](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/arod-work-lamp-gray__0134378_PE290495_S4.JPG)

Option 5 if your [lamp is like this.](http://www.globeequipment.com/Content/Images/hd8-90_1.jpg)

Note: Third and fourth option would mean that the **event** of lamp fusing out had already happened. On the other hand, rest of the options **may** mean the action happened as you *noticed*. It all depends on the context.

Comment: "burned out" is common in the US - it indicates the filament in the lightbulb burned through, so it no longer carries a current.

Comment: In InE, I'd refer it as a 'fused bulb/lamp' then. @StoneyB